# Defining output raster type in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, coordinate-system

Im trying to reproject **raster data type** **.jpg** inside a model builder, i batched the model, everything is ok besides that the **raster type** after that is in **.tiff** by default. I want those to stay in **.jpg**

Answer (score 1):

I think when you save the file,there is an option in the  window which you can choose what type of image you want to save the raster.

Comment: You can do it if you let the output as model parameter, and do it manually for every aster,  but i dont want to do it manually, i want to be automatic